# Move & remove layout objects conditionally in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, autolayout

[image]

In the UITableViewCell shown above, the "tags" underneath "Item Name Here" need to be hidden conditionally. Any remaining tags should slide left so the first tag always starts where what left edge of the "Serialized" tag is in the photo.

Given the number of tags involved in this cell and even more in similar ones in my project, what is a clean way of making this happen efficiently? Is it possible to use a UICollectionView, or can this be easily accomplished with AutoLayout?

Comment: How much work this will be to do depends to a certain extent on what your parameters are. Will whatever tags are visible always be in the same order?

Comment: Yes, they will always be in the same order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with a collection view, but that seems a bit heavy for this purpose. Unfortunately, there's no easy way to do this with constraints. Basically, the least complex way (I think) is to remove all the horizontal constraints and add them back for all the visible views. Since that requires a bit of code, rather than trying to do that in your table view controller, it would be cleaner to use a subclass or category to do the heavy lifting. One way I found to do this is with a Swift extension. This implementation requires that you add all the subviews you want to hide and slide to the left to an enclosing view; this view shouldn't have any other subviews (the current implementation only works for horizontally arranged view that slide to the left. Eventually, I'll get around to making it more general since it seems like something numerous people have asked for). The extension looks like this,

```
extension UIView {

    func setupCollapsingViews() {
        var views = self.subviews as! [UIView]
        let visibleViews = views.filter {$0.hidden == false}
        self.removeAllHorizontalConstraints()
        if visibleViews.count > 0 {
            self.remakeHorizontalConstraints(visibleViews)
        }
    }


    func unhideAll() {
        var views = self.subviews as! [UIView]
        views.map(){$0.hidden = false}
        self.setupCollapsingViews()
    }


    func hideView(view: UIView) {
        view.hidden = true
        self.setupCollapsingViews()
    }


    func revealViewAtIndex(index: Int, hide: Bool) {
        var aView = (self.subviews as! [UIView])[index]
        aView.hidden = hide
        self.setupCollapsingViews()
    }


    private func removeAllHorizontalConstraints() {
        let hAttributes: [NSLayoutAttribute] = [.Leading, .Left, .Right, .Trailing, .TrailingMargin, .LeadingMargin, .LeftMargin, .RightMargin, .CenterX]
        for con in self.constraints() as! [NSLayoutConstraint] {
            if  contains(hAttributes, con.firstAttribute) || contains(hAttributes, con.secondAttribute) {
                self.removeConstraint(con)
            }
        }
    }


    private func remakeHorizontalConstraints(views: [UIView]) {
        var viewsDict = [String:UIView]()
        var formatString = String()

        for (idx, aView) in enumerate(views) {
            viewsDict["view\(idx)"] = aView
            if idx == 0 {
                formatString += "|-[view0]"
            }else{
                formatString += "-[view\(idx)]"
            }
        }
        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(formatString, options: .DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
    }
}
```

I added that class to an Objective-C project, and used this code to test it,

```
#import "TableController.h"
#import "RDTableViewCell.h"
#import "TableViewWithCollapsibleViews-Swift.h"

@interface TableController ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *theData;
@end

@implementation TableController 

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.theData = @[@"One",@"Two",@"Three",@"Four",@"Five",@"Six",@"Seven",@"Eight",@"Nine",@"Black",@"Brown",@"Red",@"Orange",@"Yellow",@"Green",@"Blue",@"Violet",@"Gray",@"White"];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.theData.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    RDTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.mainLabel.text = self.theData[indexPath.row];
    //[cell.tagsView unhideAll]; // this needs to be called either here or in prepareForReuse in the custom cell class to "reset" the cell

    if ([self.theData[indexPath.row] hasPrefix:@"T"]) {
        [cell.tagsView hideView:cell.numberLabel];
    }else if ([self.theData[indexPath.row] hasPrefix:@"B"]) {
        [cell.tagsView hideView:cell.imageLabel];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

I've uploaded that test project here, http://jmp.sh/5EmwRyR

Comment: This worked very well and is easily reused. For others looking at this, the hierarchy of the views that you want to slide need to match the order that they are shown (left-to-right) on your layout.

Comment: @MichaelVoccola Thanks for that clarification. Originally, I sorted the views based on their origin.x values, and while this worked fine for a stand-alone view, it caused problems when it was in a cell (due to cell reuse). Part of the problem is the limitations (no stored properties) of using an extension. I'm working on a new version that subclasses the view (the one containing the tags or their equivalent).

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by programmatically setting constraints after hiding/removing the tags that don't apply.  You'll need to have a custom class for the prototype cell have each of the tags you've inserted hooked up to their own outlet.

After you've done this, in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` implementation, you would decide which tags stay and which go and then setup constraints using multiple calls like so:

```
[cell.tag2 addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cell.tag1
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:cell.tag3
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                     multiplier:0.5
                                                       constant:0]];
```

You'll need one of those calls for each of the tags you need to have laid out.

As for using a `UICollectionView`, while it might be possible I'm sure it wasn't intended to be put in a `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 0):

The effect being pursued can now be accomplished by using a UIStackView and hiding/showing the appropriate views using:

`myView.hidden = aBoolValue`

For additional flare, this can be animated such as:

```
func hideView (v:UIView) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.35) { [unowned self] in
        v.hidden = true
        v.myView.alpha = 0
    }
}
```

or

```
func showView (v:UIView) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.35) { [unowned self] in
        v.hidden = false
        v.myView.alpha = 1
    }    
}
```